# Initializing a ctype.Structure from a pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

An API I am working with have some functions for returning only a pointer while not having any python class to match.

So I have taken to using ctypes for getting the data from the pointer. This works easily enough for more simple structures like getting a struct with a single member `double position[3]` I can just

```py
pointer = api.get_pointer()
position = (ctypes.c_double * 3).from_address(pointer)
```

Given something more complex like

```c
typedef struct sFoo {
  int a,
  double b,
  long c,
} Foo;
```

I would like to be able to set initial fields of a ctype.Structure from just this pointer

```
class Foo(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [
    ("a", ctypes.c_int),
    ("b", ctypes.c_double),
    ("c", ctypes.c_long),
  ]
```

but the structure does not support `from_address` like the array does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo.from_address` is supported, but you can declare a function to return `ctypes.POINTER(Foo)` as well.  Here's an example:

**test.c**

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct sFoo {
  int a;
  double b;
  long c;
} Foo;

API Foo* get_pointer() {
    static Foo foo = { 1, 2.5, 3 };
    return &foo;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Foo(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("a", ct.c_int),
                ("b", ct.c_double),
                ("c", ct.c_long))

    # Good habit to declare debug representation of structures
    # so it knows how to print itself.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo(a={self.a}, b={self.b}, c={self.c})'

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Good habit to fully define argument types and return type
dll.get_pointer.argtypes = ()
dll.get_pointer.restype = ct.POINTER(Foo)

p = dll.get_pointer()
print(p.contents) # .contents dereferences the pointer, like *p in C.

# Just to show .from_address works as well, declare return type as void*
dll.get_pointer.restype = ct.c_void_p

p = dll.get_pointer()
print(p)
print(Foo.from_address(p))
```

Output:

```
Foo(a=1, b=2.5, c=3)
140731555266560
Foo(a=1, b=2.5, c=3)
```

Comment: The API is Python so there is no DLL for me to load and set return or argument types for, but you're right I can set the data for my ctype struct using `from_address` which reads better, thanks!

Comment: @Sindri What API in Python returns pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Seem that the method I was looking for was `cast`

```py
pointer = ctypes.cast(api.get_pointer(), ctype.POINTER(Foo))
foo = pointer.contents
print(f"foo.a = {foo.a}")
```